# How to connect to mongoDB on remote server from Angular-Spring application hosted on some other server

Tags: java, angularjs, mongodb, spring-mvc

My mongoDB is hosted on X box and Angular-Spring Application is on say Y box.
When both are on local, my application works fine, but on this server level configuration I'm getting below issue.

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to
>   connect to any servers; nested exception is
>   com.mongodb.MongoServerSelectionException: Unable to connect to any
>   servers
>
> **type** Exception
>   report
>
> **message** Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to
>   connect to any servers; nested exception is
>   com.mongodb.MongoServerSelectionException: Unable to connect to any
>   servers
>
> **description** The server encountered an
>   internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this
>   request.
>
> **exception**
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to
>   connect to any servers; nested exception is
>   com.mongodb.MongoServerSelectionException: Unable to connect to any
>   servers
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)

We have changed configuration to point to X box in all configurations

Comment: uhm, i've experienced something similar to this with postgresql, was a problem of timeout trying to connect the app with the database, are you hosting them on a private server?

Comment: its in private network.

Comment: maybe it's a problem with ssl, did you tried to connect to your db from a tool? just too see if it works

Comment: I tried accessing mongodb using SimpleMongoDbFactory and now its working fine, we were trying through MongoClient and MongoTemplate both was giving the above error.

Comment: that's great, consider to post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

By default, MongoDB bind to local interface only, it will restrict the remote connections. So to publish your remote server and make it available outside of localhost you should update mongod.conf with

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.1,<remote_server_ip>,....
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was location of jar file. I'm using Apache tomcat and jar should be kept there. Initially I thought SimpleMongoDbFactory solved my issue, later I realized it was due to jars.